jaxws-maven plugin ,jdk release
I am trying the JakartaEE10 example and got a problem compiling some example.
I have installed Payara server 6.2023.12 ,it need compiled code in version 11 but my current jdk is 21.02 , then I need to compile all as version 11 to run on Payara server.
The problem : is when a compile from NB I got a compiled code with class version 65 (21) for artifacts create by jaxws-maven plugin and version 55(11) for the ws SEI class  .
I think jaxws us te jdk referenced from NB and maven compiler use yours default (55)
The question : I know I can force maven to use specific release , but there is a way to force in the same way also jaxws.maven plugin ?
I tried also to force xnocompile for jaxws-maven plugin in the way it produce also source and after the source will copiled by mavn compiler but it doesn't work

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ... >
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>jakarta.examples.tutorial.jaxws</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>10-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>helloservice-war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>helloservice-war</name>
<description>Simple example JAX-WS web service.</description>

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-wsdl</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsgen</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sei>jakarta.tutorial.helloservice.Hello</sei>
          <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</project>

